# Storing integer values in an alphanumeric string

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a .txt with the format below, in order to create an array with a size of 26 (1 per each letter on the alphabet).

```
a 5
b 2
c 4
d 10
e 11
f 5
g 7
...
```

I tried doing this with the (non-working) code below, sending an empty vec[26] as an argument, as well as the .txt which contained the value of each word:

```
void readvalues(FILE*values, int*vec)
{
    if (values == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("Couldn't open values' file\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    int i=0;

    while (i<26) 
    {   
        fscanf(values,"%d",&vec[i]);
        printf("%d\n",vec[i]); 
        i++;
    }
}
```

When I check the printf output, I see that vec[0] is right, however this function starts storing trash on the remaining positions.
What is causing this and how can I fix it? Is there any alternative to fscanf besides fgets?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Jose You need to be checking that `fscanf` returns the number of matches you're expecting. In your current code, `1`, in R Sahu's answer, `2`.  That's why you're seeing *garbage* - because `fscanf` didn't store *anything* there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readvalues(FILE *values);

FILE *datafile;
int vec[26];

int main()
{

    datafile = fopen ( "my.txt", "r");
    readvalues(datafile);


    return 0;
}

void readvalues(FILE *values)
{
    char tmp[2];
    if (values == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("Couldn't open values' file\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 

    int i=0;

    while (i<26) 
    {   
        if(fscanf(values,"%s %d",tmp,&vec[i]));
        printf("%d\n",vec[i]); 
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your welcome,I think you understand the code and no need to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don't plan on using the characters of the alphabet from the file, you still need to add the code to read the characters. Otherwise, trying to read the numbers will be stuck at the next letter.

```
char ch;

// ....

fscanf(values,"%c %d", &ch, &vec[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I still get the same output when I add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead looping with a fixed value of 26, you may want to consider looping line-by-line until the data in the file is gone:

```
int getdata(FILE *ifp, int *data){
    char buf[256];    // potential size of leading string
    int i=0;          // offset into data array

    while (fscanf(ifp, "%s %d", buf, &data[i]) != EOF) {
        i++;   
    }    
    return i;         // return how many ints were read and processed
}
```

Then your file can have 2 lines or 2 million. You only need to make sure that `data` is large enough -- either by making that use dynamic memory or precounting the lines in the file.